# Get powershell result of HPC-PACK command in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running a Powershell command against an Microsoft HPC PACK from C#. For example:

```
ps.instance.Addcommand("get-hpcjob").AddParameter("id","123");
var res = psinstance.invoke();
```

The res[0] variable gets a lot of info and is of type "Microsoft.ComputeCluster.CCPPSH.HpcJob".
If I open it in the debug mode in the watch list, I can see all the data inside under "BaseObject" property.

It looks like:

```
res[0].BaseObject
-Name
-Id
-ChangeTime
-EnTime
..
..
..
```

The problem is that I can't seems to find how to get to this date in runtime.
I tried res[0][0] but I get an error.

I be glad if someone can help getting the Job info or in general helping with working against the HPC with Powershell commands.

Comment: Which bit do you need? `Name`? `Id`? `ChangeTime`? What do you mean by `get to this date in runtime`

Comment: `dynamic obj = res[0].BaseObject;  Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. I used the properties names I saw in the debug and it worked.